# EmbeddedKafka not working cause an Scala error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have a working spring-boot java-gradle-based service that can produce and consume Kafka messages. But I can't create an integration test using spring-kafka-test library with @EmbeddedKafka annotation or using @ClassRule way. In both ways, I end up with the same error (pointed below regarding Scala). If anybody has any clue about what could be happening behind the scenes it would be very helpful.

Spring boot version: 2.1.6.RELEASE
Spring Kafka version: 2.2.7.RELEASE

Producer Config:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    private String bootstrapAddress;

    public KafkaProducerConfig(@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapAddress) {
        this.bootstrapAddress = bootstrapAddress;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Greeting> greetingProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Greeting> greetingKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(greetingProducerFactory());
    }
}
```

Producer Code:

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducer {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Greeting> kafkaTemplate;

    @Value(value = "${kiosk.kafka.topic.greeting}")
    private String greetingTopicName;

    public void sendMessage(Greeting greeting) {

        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Greeting>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(greetingTopicName, greeting);

        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Greeting>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Greeting> result) {
                System.out.println("Sent greeting=[" + greeting + "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata().offset() + "]");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to send greeting=[" + greeting + "] due to : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

properties file:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.embedded.kafka.brokers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=1
```

And I tried the test with both ways and the same error while starting the test:

Test class rule:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
public class PKafkaProducerClassRuleTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(PKafkaProducerClassRuleTest.class);

    private static String SENDER_TOPIC = "sender.t";

    static {
        System.setProperty(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.BROKER_LIST_PROPERTY, "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
    }

    @Autowired
    private PinPadKafkaProducer sender;

    private KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container;

    private BlockingQueue<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records;

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka =
        new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, SENDER_TOPIC);
```

Test with EmbeddedKafka:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
    topics = {
        "sender.t" })
public class PKafkaProducerEmbeddedKafkaTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(PKafkaProducerEmbeddedKafkaTest.class);

    private static String SENDER_TOPIC = "sender.t";

    static {
        System.setProperty(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.BROKER_LIST_PROPERTY,
            "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
    }

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

    @Autowired
    private PinPadKafkaProducer sender;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        sender.sendMessage(new Greeting("msgtest", "nametest"));
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("testGroup", "true", this.embeddedKafka);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps);
        Consumer<Integer, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer();
        this.embeddedKafka.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, SENDER_TOPIC);
        ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> replies = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer);
        assertThat(replies.count()).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
    }

}
```

Error in both scenarios:

```
19/11/2019 13:51:56.774+0100 ERROR o.s.t.c.TestContextManager [] - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@e9cee0d] to prepare test instance [com.goldcar.kiosk.PKafkaProducerEmbeddedKafkaTest@39271181]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:405)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:621)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:365)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<init>(EndPoint.scala:32)
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<clinit>(EndPoint.scala)
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:68)
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:781)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createBrokerConfig(TestUtils.scala:234)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils.createBrokerConfig(TestUtils.scala)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.createBrokerProperties(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:239)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Show your dependencies configuration, please.

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan, I just show your comment. Thanks a lot for your interest and response, surely if I had wrote my gradle config, you guys would have spotted the error even faster.

Comment: Surely I see that Gary has nailed it for you. Please, don't hesitate to raise a GH issue to improve the mentioned doc for including a Gradle config as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have mis-matched versions of kafka jars on the classpath.

This will happen if you use a different `kafka-clients` version than the default set by Boot.

See [this appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/#deps-for-21x) for an example for how to override all kafka jar versions.

> When you use `spring-kafka-test` (version 2.2.x) with the 2.1.x `kafka-clients` jar, you need to override certain transitive dependencies, as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.kafka.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.kafka.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

> Note that when switching to scala 2.12 (recommended for 2.1.x and higher), the 2.11 version must be excluded from `spring-kafka-test`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick resposne Gary. You were absolutely right, that was the problem. After some digging, I managed to translate the dependencies you pointed from maven to gradle, don't know if I can submit them to you in any way, in any case I am stating below for anyone that arrives to this page. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Feel free to issue a pull request against the [appendix](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/master/src/reference/asciidoc/appendix.adoc). It is currently commented out on master (since it uses the latest 2.3.1 clients) but we can back-port it to the 2.2.x docs).

Answer (score 2):

Solution applying using @Gary Russell answer in gradle:

gradle.properties:

```
spring_kafka_test_version=2.2.7.RELEASE
kafka_test_version=2.1.1
kafka_clients_test_version=2.1.1
```

build.gradle:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka'
implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: kafka_clients_test_version
implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.12', version: kafka_test_version

testImplementation (group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka-test', version: spring_kafka_test_version) {
    exclude module: 'kafka_2.11'
}
testImplementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.12', version: kafka_test_version, classifier: 'test'
testImplementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: kafka_clients_test_version
```

Comment: I updated [the appendix in the documentation to show the gradle version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.12.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#deps-for-21x).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gary, I did not any PR to Spring yet so I was still reading the documentation.  I checked and your version is cleaner than mine.